# PYTHON LISTA INSERTAR

Tags: python-3.x

Uso este simple ejemplo para entender qu'e sucede porque no funciona la llamada al metodo insertar.
python 3.0.  En la clase main.py probe lista = Lista() y me da error(lista = Lista()
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable), probe lista = () tampoco llama al m'etodo insertar
y no me doy cuenta.

```
import  Lista
import  Nodo

class Main:

lista = Lista

while True:
    print ('*** MENU********')
    print ('1_ INSERTAR*****')
    print ('4_ SALIR********')
    try:
        opcion = int(input('ELIJA UNA OPCION: \n'))
        print ('opcion = ', opcion)
        if (opcion == 1):
            nodo = Nodo
            nodo.nombre = input('ESCRIBA EL NOMBRE. \n')
            nodo.edad = int(input('ESCRIBA LA EDAD. \n'))
            lista.insertar(nodo)
        elif opcion == 4:
            break
    except:
        print ('HUBO UN ERROR')

import  Nodo
class Lista:
def __init__(self):
    self.raiz = Nodo()

def insertar(self, nodo):
    print ('paso por aca1')
    if self.raiz.nombre == None:
        self.raiz = nodo
    else:
        aux = self.raiz
        while True:
            if aux.siguiente == None:
                aux.siguiente = nodo
                break
            else:
                aux = aux.siguiente

class Nodo:

def __init__(self):
    self.nombre = None
    self.edad = 0
    self.siguiente = None
```

Comment: Por favor indenta bien tu código, tal como está te puedo decir que todo está mal

Comment: Tienes un import Lista y mas adelante defines una clase Lista. Pero en la línea `lista=Lista` el simbolo `Lista` se refiere todavía al módulo y no a la clase. Mejor usas otro nombre para el modulo para evitar confusiones, o quitas ese `import` que no veo que haga nada necesario. Lo mismo con `Nodo`

Comment: Antes que todo, gracias por tu tiempo.
(FILE: Nodo.py OK)
(FILE: Lista1.py
import Nodo
class Lista:
def __init__(  #ok
def insertar(  #ok
import Nodo)
(FILE: Main.py 
class Main:
lista = Lista()
nodo = Nodo()
no uso: import Lista1 ?
        import Nodo   ?
Si uso lista = Lista1() obtengo un error
Si uso lista = Lista() obtengo un error
en ambos caso Lista, Lista1 no esta definida.
Entiendo lo que me comentas pero no me doy cuenta en ese increiblemente simple ejemplo.
Copie y pegue tu c'odigo y obtengo el mismo error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes varios errores del mismo tipo:

```
lista = Lista
nodo = Nodo
```

La forma de instanciar un objeto es llamar a la clase pasando parámetros:

```
lista = Lista()
nodo = Nodo()
```

Hay que entender las diferencias:

```
1. El nombre del archivo que contiene el código, el que se pone en el `import`; no tiene otro uso.

2. El nombre de la clase que está definida dentro de ese archivo. El nombre de la clase puede ser cualquiera (sin relación con el nombre del archivo). Ese nombre lo usas para instanciar objetos.
```

**Ejemplo**

Tienes una archivo `proceso.py` que contiene lo siguiente:

*proceso.py*

```
class Proc:
    def __init__(self, duracion):
        self._duracion = duracion
```

y luego en el main lo usas:

*main.py*

```
import proceso

pr = proceso.Proc(10)  # Instancias un objeto Proc con parámetro 10.
```

#### Demo

Las listas son objetos básicos en Python; reimplementarlas a mano es absurdo. Anyway, este es tu código reordenado y corregido:

```
class Nodo:

    def __init__(self):
        self.nombre = None
        self.edad = 0
        self.siguiente = None

class Lista:
    def __init__(self):
        self.raiz = Nodo()

    def insertar(self, nodo):
        print ('paso por aca1')
        if self.raiz.nombre == None:
            self.raiz = nodo
        else:
            aux = self.raiz
            while True:
                if aux.siguiente == None:
                    aux.siguiente = nodo
                    break
                else:
                    aux = aux.siguiente


class Main:
    lista = Lista()

    while True:
        print ('*** MENU********')
        print ('1_ INSERTAR*****')
        print ('4_ SALIR********')
        try:
            opcion = int(input('ELIJA UNA OPCION: \n'))
            print ('opcion = ', opcion)
            if (opcion == 1):
                nodo = Nodo()
                nodo.nombre = input('ESCRIBA EL NOMBRE. \n')
                nodo.edad = int(input('ESCRIBA LA EDAD. \n'))
                lista.insertar(nodo)
            elif opcion == 4:
                break
        except:
            print ('HUBO UN ERROR')
```

produce:

```
*** MENU********
1_ INSERTAR*****
4_ SALIR********
ELIJA UNA OPCION: 
1
opcion =  1
ESCRIBA EL NOMBRE. 
Candid Moe
ESCRIBA LA EDAD. 
65
paso por aca1
*** MENU********
1_ INSERTAR*****
4_ SALIR********
ELIJA UNA OPCION: 
4
opcion =  4

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Sha Ta!... S'e que el manejo de listas est'a definido y que esto no "estaria bien".  Es un ejercicio que me puse a resolver probando algo y degenero en que no andaba.  Intente usar esto un poco m'as simple pero FAIL AGAIN!. Y es un error tan torpe que no me daba cuenta.  Muchisimas gracias por tu tiempo y tu aclaraci'on. Cuidate. C.Moe.